# GC Issue when running tomcat with TLSv1.2

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, ssl, garbage-collection

We have been facing a performance issue with tomcat7/java8 when we run it with ssl enabled.

We see frequent long Full GC's occurring and the other strange behavior that we observe is - the first Full GC is not able to collect much from old gen but in the second subsequent run it collects a lot of garbage and because the first Full GC is ineffective the second one is triggered with in a few minutes interval.

> 2018-02-09T13:16:24.333-0800: 4230.908: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 95848K->0K(1993216K)] [ParOldGen: 6291073K->5837813K(6291456K)] 6386922K->5837813K(8284672K), [Metaspace: 33316K->33313K(1079296K)], 6.9081824 secs] [Times: user=30.68 sys=0.33, real=6.91 secs]
>
> 2018-02-09T13:21:02.067-0800: 4508.643: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 91268K->0K(2000384K)] [ParOldGen: 6288350K->1355941K(6291456K)] 6379619K->1355941K(8291840K), [Metaspace: 33313K->33225K(1079296K)], 2.1279458 secs] [Times: user=13.88 sys=0.08, real=2.12 secs]
>
> 2018-02-09T14:13:36.719-0800: 7663.294: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 85011K->0K(2004480K)] [ParOldGen: 6288173K->5361047K(6291456K)] 6373184K->5361047K(8295936K), [Metaspace: 33251K->33251K(1079296K)], 4.8433826 secs] [Times: user=21.24 sys=0.07, real=4.84 secs]
>
> 2018-02-09T14:23:47.153-0800: 8273.729: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 89494K->0K(1998336K)] [ParOldGen: 6288199K->1789523K(6291456K)] 6377694K->1789523K(8289792K), [Metaspace: 33271K->33271K(1079296K)], 2.2011957 secs] [Times: user=13.46 sys=0.06, real=2.20 secs]
>
> 2018-02-09T15:09:56.091-0800: 11042.666: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 87639K->0K(1998848K)] [ParOldGen: 6287278K->4822169K(6291456K)] 6374918K->4822169K(8290304K), [Metaspace: 33285K->33285K(1079296K)], 4.4801296 secs] [Times: user=20.02 sys=0.08, real=4.48 secs]
>
> 2018-02-09T15:25:38.142-0800: 11984.718: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 84340K->0K(1997824K)] [ParOldGen: 6288212K->2259748K(6291456K)] 6372552K->2259748K(8289280K), [Metaspace: 33304K->33304K(1079296K)], 2.5007909 secs] [Times: user=14.17 sys=0.06, real=2.50 secs]

On looking into the heap dumps we see most of the `byte[]` which are biggest consumers of heap have a immediate dominator in `sun.security` package.

Also we have `sessionCacheSize="1000"` and `sessionTimeout="1"` but the instances of `sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl` are much more than 1K and if I look at their `lastUsedTime` there are many instances which should have been garbage collected in the last Full GC. The reason we are running with small cache size and time out is because our client uses a new https request for every request. Below are our connector settings:

> > connectionTimeout="3600"
> >     executor="tomcatThreadPool"
> >     maxKeepAliveRequests="15" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
> >     sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
> >     port="${nio.https.port}" sessionCacheSize="1000" sessionTimeout="1"
> >     protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
> >     scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
> >     keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass=""
> >     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" redirectPort="${nio.https.port}"/>

Should I be updating some other connector setting for short lived session objects?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have `sessionTimeout="1"` which means that probably every request from the same client will require a TLS session renegotiation. Are you sure that it what you want? It's probably gonna generate... lots of garbage! Does the client have a new (OS) process for each new request? No possibility for keep-alive or TLS session keep-alive?

Comment: Are you sure that running the same application without SSL doesn't end with the same problem ? Did you run it for some hours ?

Comment: There's not much point in caching 1000 sessions if they are only going to live for a second each. Try something more realistic like 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I will add some more context - we had started the test with no ssl cache settings and our Full GC times then were above 10 secs then we realized the client was making a new connection with every request and thus we added the cache settings and since then GC times have improved (without SSL they are less than 1 sec) but the issue is they are still over 1 sec and in every cycle the first GC is considerably longer and is not very effective. Thanks!